# How to use aggregation in elasticsearch? I tried with following code but shows error

Tags: php, codeigniter, elasticsearch

My Code:

```
$test1  = '{
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                      "query": "*"
                    }
             },
            "aggs": {
                    "AGE": {
                      "filter": {
                        "range": {
                          "age": { }
                        }
                      }
                    }
            },
            "sort": { 
                "age": {
                    "order": "desc" 
                } 
            }
    }';
$response = $this->elasticsearch->advancedquery("comment", $test1);
```

DB name is set by default in class file and `("comment", $test1);` 'comment' is the table name.
Anything wrong in this query?
When I run the query, I am getting the following error

```
 [root_cause] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => illegal_argument_exception
                        [reason] => Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [age] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.
                    )

            )
```

Answer (score 2):

In 5.x version, `FieldData` is  disabled on text Fields By default. You need to enable them if you want.

As per [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#_fielddata_is_disabled_on_literal_text_literal_fields_by_default)

> Fielddata can consume a lot of heap space, especially when loading high cardinality text fields. Once fielddata has been loaded into the heap, it remains there for the lifetime of the segment. Also, loading fielddata is an expensive process which can cause users to experience latency hits. This is why fielddata is disabled by default.

If you want to run aggregation on the field, you need to enable it like:

```
PUT my_index/_mapping/my_type
{
   "properties": {
   "age": { 
   "type":     "text",
   "fielddata": true
    }
   }
 }
```

Hope this helps!!